# How to get offline messages count for a JabberID

Tags: php, xmpp, chat, offline, ejabberd

In my application, I wanna show the total number of offline messages for each JabberId on web as well as mobile app. Hence i wanna create an API for this by which i can get the offline messages count from the Ejabberd  server.
This type of functionality is working on ejabberd admin panel, I wanna same on my web.

[image: Ejabberd Admin Panel]

Is there any command, script or module by which i can get the offline messages count, Please tell me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have `mod_admin_extra` module enabled, you have a command for that: `ejabberdctl get_offline_count user domain`

```
 $ ejabberdctl help get_offline_count 

  Command Name: get_offline_count

  Arguments: user::binary
             server::binary

  Returns: res::integer

  Tags:  offline

  Description:  Get the number of unread offline messages
```

For example:

```
$ ejabberdctl get_offline_count test localhost
0
```

All commands can also be leverage using ReST or XMLRPC API.

Comment: Hi Mickael, I have installed mod_admin_extra into my ejabberd from this link: https://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/mod_admin_extra/trunk/src/mod_admin_extra.erl. This module is running fine(I have checked some commands of this module like 'num_active_users', etc), But  'get_offline_count' command is not present in this module. The Error is: root@D-5:/# ejabberdctl help get_offline_count
Error: not command found that match: "get_offline_count"
Please help where i am wrong, Thanks for reply.

Comment: This is wrong. mod_admin_extra is a standard module in ejabberd now. You have nothing to install, you should just enable it in configuration.

Comment: Thanks Mickael for the help. Actually i have ejabberd 2.1.13, I have added this command into my mod_admin_extra module and it is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use *mod_offline* module like that `mod_offline:get_queue_length(UserId,Server)` 
for getting total number of offline message of specific user(if mod_offline module enabled).